# I can't install cgpt in Arch Linux using Pacman, what to do?

Tags: arch-linux, terminal, software-installation, pacman, command-not-found

I've been unable to install cgpt in Arch Linux.

I don't know what it is, but it's needed for a script.

Here is the output of my Terminal:

```
# pacman -S cgpt
error: target not found: cgpt
# cgpt
-bash: cgpt: command not found
```

How to get pacman to work?

Searching `"error: target not found: cgpt"` with brackets on Google doesn't give results, showing this is very unique.

This is WSL2, which shouldn't matter in this case.

I tried installing vboot-utils and got the same error.

Comment: Dependency for what? Can you post the text from the error?

Comment: I'm using a script that needs it, it's about creating an image file from an archive and it says did you install cgpt? Apt-get has it, but pacman doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arch Linux official repos don't have `vboot-utils` (provides `cgpt`). Build from [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/vboot-utils/).  Prebuilt binary available in [`chaotic-aur`](https://aur.chaotic.cx/). Here is the [PKGBUILD](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/plain/PKGBUILD?h=vboot-utils).

Comment: I wanna add a big thank you, since chaotic-aur has worked perfect for me for a long time!